# trying to run .bat file along with some conditional loops in a .ps1 file

Tags: powershell

i want to run some conditional looping code along with other task like running a .bat file in one .ps1 file. I dont have sound knowledge in poweershell but i am trying to do this.
 i tried to run the file but only batch file is executing successfully but not the code that needs to perform a different tasks in the process.
i tried using this command to run .batch file
cmd.exe /k ""c:\Users\ADM_SPANCHADULA\Desktop\status_check\status.bat" & powershell"
which is executing fine. but the remaining part

```
cd C:\Users\ADM_SPANCHADULA\Desktop\status_check

cmd.exe /c "c:\Users\ADM_SPANCHADULA\Desktop\status_check\status.bat" 
"hello world " | Out-Host

$a=0
Do {
    $output1 = Compare-Object (get-content "Job_status.txt")  (get-content "done.txt")
    $output2 = Compare-Object (get-content "Job_status.txt")  (get-content "warn.txt")

    if ( $output1 = "" ) {
        $a = 1 
        $a|Out-Host
    } elseif ( $output2 = "" ) {
        $a = 1 
        $a|Out-Host
    } else  { 
        echo "looping " 
    }
} while ( $a -gt 0 )
```

is not executing .
 can someone please help me out.

Comment: Your first line runs the batch and keeps the cmd session `/k` to run run a different powershell session. If you exit that powershell the first powershell session can continue. So simply remove the `& powershell`

Comment: And change `/k` to `/c` otherwise you will have to manually exit the cmd session.

Comment: thanks for the reply. @LotPings :)

Comment: i have a new issue. irrespective og the code which i wrote it is just executing the lines. but not untill the condition in the loop satisfies... '' So please help to rectify this error

Comment: This is a new question. What do you expect? **Until** one of the diff command has an empty result no if will trigger and $a will have the value 0. The **while** condition won't loop. BTW the tmp files aren't necessary and your indentation is terrible. I'll edit your code.

Comment: thank you very much for your help and sorry for the worst coding. .